# Angular6 What's browserTarget

Tags: angular, angular6

Here is a standard angular.json file

```
"projects": {
  "myApp": {
     [...]
     "architect": {
       "build": {
         [...]
         "configurations": {
           "production": { [...] },
           "debug": { [...] }
         }
       },
       "serve": {
         [...]
         "configurations": {
           "production": {
             "browserTarget": "myApp:build:production"
           },
           "debug": {
             "browserTarget": "myApp:build:debug"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

I don't understand what's the `browserTarget` setting for ?
I couldn't find any documentation, it seems that I'd have to dig into `@angular-devkit` ...

Answer (score 20):

`browserTarget` is a setting that maps a configuration to a build target e.g. `build`, `serve`, `test`, `lint`. It's kind of a funny name. To be honest I don't know why it's called `browserTarget` instead of just `target`.

Further reading [here at the angular.io docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements).

Comment: It is called `browserTarget` because Angular has another property `serverTarget` which is used when running Angular Universal (server-side rendering).

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Angular v17, `browserTarget` is deprecated and `buildTarget` should be used instead (which makes more sense as a name).

[image]

Reference: https://angular.io/cli/serve